# Swift static property initilizers are lazy why I could declared it as a constant

Tags: swift, initialization

As far as I known (see reference A), Static property initilizers are lazy, and I found the following description by the [office documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

> You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var
>   keyword) because its initial value might not be retrieved until after
>   instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always
>   have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be
>   declared as lazy.

From the above information, I think I couldn't define the static property as a constant variable and I made a tryout, it turns out I can do that without triggering any error from the compiler.

Example:

```
class Person {
    static let firstNaID = "First Name"
    static let lastNaID = "Last Name"
}
```

**Question**: Is this a bug of the Swift 3.0.1 or I was wrong.

**Reference A**: Neuburg. M.2016. *IOS 10 Programming Fundamental with Swift*. P127

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: @Dalmas you know wrong. It's easy to test and prove to yourself that `static` initializers are lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neuburg M. is [drawing a distinction](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_lazy_initialization) between static properties and instance properties. You are pretending to ignore that distinction. But you cannot ignore it; they are totally different things, used for different purposes.

In this code:

```
class Person { // let's declare a static property
    static let firstNaID = "First Name"
}
```

... `firstNaID` is *already* lazy. But now try to do this:

```
class Person { // let's declare an instance property
    lazy let firstNaID : String = "First Name" // error
}
```

You can't; as things stand (up thru Swift 3.1), you have to say `lazy var` instead — and when you do, you get a lazy instance property.

Your `static let` declaration thus doesn't accomplish what `lazy let` wanted to accomplish, because a static property is not an instance property.

Comment: "static property is not an instance property." I think that's the point! Many thanks

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much always know what Neuburg M. means. — The distinction in question is introduced here http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime _before_ the section you cited.

Comment: Thanks for your book and help, programming is not easy but its fun.

Comment: It _is_ fun, and the mental challenge is part of what makes it fun! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about *type properties*

Form the same chapter of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

> **Type Properties**
>
> ... Type properties are useful for defining values that are universal to all instances of a particular type, such as a constant property that all instances can use ...
>
> Stored type properties can be variables or constants. Computed type properties are always declared as variable properties, in the same way as computed instance properties.
>
> NOTE
>
> ...
>
> **Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access**. They are guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, **and they do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier**.

Comment: Yes I think I mixed up the instance property and the class/static property, Many thanks for your time and help :)